# chilkat method for reading a email message body

Tags: vb.net, chilkat, chilkat-email

How to get the message body using chilkat .What is the method to retrieve the message body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their online docs the [Email](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vbnetEmailRef.html) class has a property called [Body](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vbnetEmailDoc.html#prop000) that I would assume is what you're looking for?

So it would just be:

```
Dim obj As New Chilkat.Email()
Dim bodyText As String = obj.Body
```

Or if you want to specify HTML vs Plain Text you could use the `GetHtmlBody` and `GetPlainTextBody` methods of the same object.

Edit: In response to comments.

In that sample, try changing the line:

```
bundle = mailman.GetAllHeaders(1)
```

to

```
bundle = mailman.CopyMail()
```

And inside the loop you should be able to add:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & email.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason my program went non responding...Can you update your answer in reference to this code http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/pop3_gmail.asp

Comment: +1 for showing me that there was a online reference documentation...SAD I need 15 reps to upvote :(

Comment: @abcd: Well, I've never actually used chilkat and I don't have access to that component, but I've added some guesses to how you could change that sample to retrieve the bodies as well. Though if your app stops responding, is it possible that it's trying to download some huge emails (or a lot of them) so that it will just take a very long time? I'd suggest creating a new gmail account, delete any "new joiner" emails and then sending one or two very small emails to that account and trying to test with that to avoid those kinds of issues.

Comment: That's what I tried before asking here ...let try it again with a new account :)

Comment: I changed it as you said with a new account it is still not working.